# Error Parsing JSON Data in MySql using NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, fetch

I am working on a project that using Node Js to connect my web API to local MySql db, I have no error message appear when writing the code in VS Code, but I get no response when testing the API in postman. here my code:

```
app.post('/enduser', (req, res) => {
  let POST_ENDUSER_QUERY =  {
    project_type: req.body.project_type,
    status: req.body.status,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    endUser_name: req.body.endUser_name,
    location: req.body.location,
    cp_1: req.body.cp_1,
    cp1_hp: req.body.cp1_hp,
    cp1_jpos: req.body.cp1_jpos,
    cp_2: req.body.cp_1,
    cp2_hp: req.body.cp1_hp,
    cp2_jpos: req.body.cp1_jpos,
    quot_num: req.body.quot_num,
    quot_date: req.body.quot_date,
    note: req.body.note,
    image: req.body.image,
    estimated_value: req.body.estimated_value
  };
  if (!POST_ENDUSER_QUERY) {
    return res.status(400).send({ err: true, message: 'Please project name' });
  }

  let query = `INSERT INTO enduser_tbl (project_type, status, subject, endUser_name, location, cp_1, cp1_hp, cp1_jpos, cp_2, cp2_hp, cp2_jpos, quot_num,quot_date, note, image, estimated_value) VALUES (
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.project_type}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.status}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.subject}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.endUser_name}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.location}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp_1}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp1_hp}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp1_jpos}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp_2}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp2_hp}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp2_jpos}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.quot_num}'.
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.quot_date}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.note}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.image}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.estimated_value}'
    ),`;
  dbConn.query(query, ( err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    return res.status(200).json({"status": 200, "err" : null, "response": results});
  });
});
```

using postman, this is my result: 
[image]

in terminal, I get problem like this:

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.\n" +
    "    '2007-05-06',\n" +
    "    'nfjhbfahbfas',\n" +
    "    'null',\n" +
    "    ''\n" +
    "    ),' at line 13",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
```

Any Idea what's going wrong with the code?

Comment: thanks for your response,,, I have no idea, where is the "\n" coming from,, and can you give me more explanation about proofing the values before injecting to sql-server ... I tried with similar code, but sending shot data is working

Comment: There is a comma at the end of your query., Try removing that. basically this `),`;`

Comment: okay thanks, that really help me... I got where is the problem...